# How to Get Image Url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, path

I am saving user profile image in my website directory where each user image is saved under separate folder. Each Folder and image are named as `userid`. In each folder currently can save one image from same image extension but multiple from different extention like below. Now I need to get the `any one` image path/url based on query like where folder name equal to userid.How can I achieve this in my laravel code.I don't have any idea for this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below statement to get image.

```
$path = '/images/users/'.$userId;
<img src="{{$path}}" />
```

Adding slash in start will go to public folder and then search from given path.